# A iterator/generator can be considered a stream?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I'm reading the SICP and ended up in the part of streams.

Would a python iterator/generator can be considered a stream?

This iterator for example:

```
class MyNumbers:
  def __iter__(self):
    self.a = 1
    return self

  def __next__(self):
    x = self.a
    self.a += 1
    return x

myclass = MyNumbers()
myiter = iter(myclass)

print(next(myiter))
print(next(myiter))
print(next(myiter))
print(next(myiter))
print(next(myiter))
```

satisfies the definition:

> a stream is a sequence of data elements made available over time. A stream can be thought of as items on a conveyor belt being processed one at a time rather than in large batches.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_(computing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikipedia article you quote from, continues with:

> In object-oriented programming, input streams are generally implemented as iterators.

So, there you go ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> Would a python iterator/generator can be considered a stream?

No.

Basically, an iterator lazily traverses a sequence while a stream is a lazy sequence.

The difference between iterators and stream becomes clearer with the example you gave, an infinite sequence of natural numbers.

### Iterator

This is a rather simplistic iterator, only with method `next()` implemented. This implementation is not iterable and does not conform with with python's [iterator protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types); however, it will make evident the differences with the stream implementation below.

```
class Iterator:
     def __init__(self, state=1, compute=lambda x: x + 1):
         self.state = state
         self.compute = compute
     def next(self):
         current, self.state = self.state, self.compute(self.state)
         return current

natural_number = Iterator()
print(natural_number.next()) # 1
print(natural_number.next()) # 2
print(natural_number.next()) # 3
```

Every time `next()` is evoked, it returns the current element of the sequence and mutates the iterator's state.

### Stream

Accordingly with SICP[2](https://xuanji.appspot.com/isicp/3-5-streams.html), a stream can be defined by its first element, `car()`, and the rest of the stream, `cdr()`. In python, streams can be implemented as lazy linked lists constructed recursively.

```
class Stream:
    def __init__(self, state=1, f=lambda x: x+1):
        self.state = state
        self.compute = f
    def car(self):
        return self.state
    def cdr(self):
        return Stream(self.compute(self.state), self.compute)

sequence_of_natural_numbers = Stream()      
sequence_of_natural_numbers.car()             # 1
sequence_of_natural_numbers.car()             # 1
sequence_of_natural_numbers.cdr().car()       # 2
sequence_of_natural_numbers.cdr().cdr().car() # 3
```

Whenever `car()` is evoked, it always returns the same element, the first element of the sequence. `crd()` returns a new `Stream` with the computed state. In this case the stream state is never mutated.

If you wonder if streams are useful, I would recommend you to read this paper [Classical (Co)Recursion: Programming](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.06913), which provides a practical implementation and some applications of streams.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that an *iterable* is a stream, while an *iterator* is a (possibly, or even usually) separate value used to actually iterate over the stream. The OP's example is both an iterator (defining `__next__`) and an iterable (defining `__iter__`).

Answer (score 0):

Your example is both an iterable (a class that defines `__iter__`) and an iterator (a class that defines `__next__`). It's more accurate to say that a stream is an iterable, and an iterator is a value (possibly the stream itself) used to iterate over the stream.

Here's your example, separating the iterator from the iterable.

```
class MyNumbers:
    def __init__(self, start=1):
        self.start = start

    def __iter__(self):
        return MyNumbersIterator(self.start)


class MyNumbersIterator:
    def __init__(self, start):
        self.value = start

    def __next__(self):
        x = self.value
        self.value += 1
        return x


# prints the numbers 10, 11, 12, ..., 19
for x in itertools.islice(MyNumbers(10), 10):
    print(x)
```

`MyNumbers` is the stream: it represents a increasing sequence of numbers from `start`.

`MyNumbersIterator` provides an *independent* iterator over that stream; you can have multiple iterators using the same iterable.

```
x = MyNumbers(10)
i1 = iter(x)
i2 = iter(x)
assert next(i1) == 10  # Does not affect i2
assert next(i2) == 10
```